# Get size of plot in pixels in R

Tags: r, plot, pheatmap

I am generating a heatmap in R with lots of rows.
TL;DR  how do I get the real size of a plot in R?

```
df=data.frame(one=1:100,two=101:200,three=201:300)
names=1:100
names=paste0("Cell",names)
rownames(df)=(names)
pheatmap(df,scale="row")
```

[image: default image fits in window]
**default image fits in window, but we can't read row names.**

`pheatmap(df,scale="row",cellheight = 10)`
[image: Changing settings causes image to not fit in window]
**changing the cell height lets us read row names but now the image doesn't fit in the window!**

In this example i am using `pheatmap`, but also run into this stuff with other plot generating packages.

While I've grown to expect frustrating behavior like this from R and by trial and error could make an appropriately size image for the plot, this seems like something that I should be able to get from the program?

Is there a way to get the dimensions of the plot automatically so that I can create  correctly size PDF or PNG for it?

Comment: it's up to you to tell R how large you want the plotting device. You can specify the size of the plotting window to the same size as your pdf or png.

Comment: But the short answer to your question is `dev.size(units = "px")`

Comment: @AllanCameron  when I make an image device like `png("myplot.png")`  the `dev.size` is just what ever size the plotting device is, and has nothing to do with the actual size of the plot I'm putting in it. ie my plot is ~1200px tall at 72dpi, but I found that out by trial and error.

Comment: I see. Most plots in R are drawn in a relative scale, so they resize according to the window size. `pheatmap` must be specifying the plot in absolute values. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `pheatmap` uses grid graphics to draw its plots, and specifies the size of its elements in "bigpts" where 72 "bigpts" == 1 inch. If you have lots of rows and specify a reasonable row height, this will exceed the plotting window.

Because it is specified as a `gtree`, we can actually access the height and width of the components and use them to set the dimensions of our png or pdf.

This function will harvest the total height and width in inches of a plot, returning them in a named list:

```
get_plot_dims <- function(heat_map)
{
  plot_height <- sum(sapply(heat_map$gtable$heights, grid::convertHeight, "in"))
  plot_width  <- sum(sapply(heat_map$gtable$widths, grid::convertWidth, "in"))
  return(list(height = plot_height, width = plot_width))
}
```

We can use this to specify the dimensions of our plotting device:

```
my_plot <- pheatmap(df,scale="row", cellheight = 10)
plot_dims <- get_plot_dims(my_plot)

png("plot.png", height = plot_dims$height, width = plot_dims$width, units = "in", res = 72)
my_plot
dev.off()
```

Which gives the desired plot

[image]

Note that this is not a general solution for R plots, but specific to `pheatmap` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the work you put in.  I see now that the issue is most of these objects just resize to fit their container, and I just found a weird way to make the plot take on a set size.  So I am trying to make the image device match the size of the plot while R tries to make the plot match the size of the image device... blah.

Comment: Exactly @jeffpkamp. I took years to get my head round that - I'm impressed at your insight!