# how can we know the dev.size unit in a random R script?

Tags: r

I am new to R (learning on my own).. hopefully my question does not seem irrelevant for this platform ..

I am using a script from a colleague to generate a pheatmap. when running the script I got a cropped pheatmap.
my questions are the following:

does the dev size change from a PC to another?
how can I know what is the unit used in a random script? for example I know that when running dev size the default unit is inches..
I tried to change the plotting area to fit with the script and this by trying the function dev new  ==> THIS OPENED A NEW  R graphic device (inactive) ..

##here is the script

```
pheatmap(t(as.matrix(patients.data2)),scale = "none", 
         color=c("whitesmoke","black","red"), cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_cols = FALSE,
         border_color = NA,
         angle_col = c("45"), fontsize =5.6, cellheight=6.2, cellwidth = 11, legend = TRUE,
         legend_breaks=c(0,1,2), legend_labels= c("Not detected" , "Detected", "Missing data"))
```

## note that my devsize gave the following result:

[1] 6.00000 3.53125

#the cell height and cell width in this script are as provided by a colleague, if I change them to smaller values ==> this gives an asymetric plot with blurry x and y labels ..

I hope I explained well the issue and looking forward for any help!

Thanks!
Sara

Answer (score 0):

The function `pheatmap` isn't like the base plot, in terms of plot size. See this question and answer to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61876386/5329073
It started as a different question, but Allan Cameron provided a method to make sure it will look the same by specifying the size of the plotting window.